# Django/Daphne/Nginx Websockets not connecting

Tags: python, django, websocket

I am using Django with Daphne and Nginx to run my websockets. Everything was working fine for months in production, however just a couple days ago my websockets wouldn't connect saying "WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain:8001/clips/509/' failed: ".

I checked the server logs and this is in the output

```
2022-04-07 16:57:22,970 ERROR    [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py:2839:processHandshake
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/txaio/tx.py:366:as_future
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/ws_protocol.py:72:onConnect
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: --- <exception caught here> ---
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/server.py:200:create_application
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/routing.py:54:__call__
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py:35:__call__
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py:53:valid_origin
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py:72:validate_origin
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py:73:<genexpr>
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /home/django/Odyssey/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py:97:match_allowed_origin
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py:376:urlparse
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: /usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py:430:urlsplit
Apr 07 16:57:22 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 python[1276]: ]
```

I don't understand why this happened all of the sudden, is it maybe a dependency got updated or deprecated?

Comment: Have you been able to replicate the same issue on a development machine?

Answer (score 1):

This is because a fix in **urllib3**. AllowedHostsOriginValidator is broked. I solved this editing my **asgi.py** file.

I changed my "application" definition from this:

```
import os

from .wsgi import *
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault(
    'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
    'manager.settings.production'
)

from .routing import websocket_urlpatterns
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        )
    ) 
})
```

to this:

```
import os

from .wsgi import *
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault(
    'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
    'manager.settings.production'
)

from .routing import websocket_urlpatterns
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        ) 
    )
})
```

More info here: https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1716

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by editing the redis.service file

> nano /etc/systemd/system/redis.service

> ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

> ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c "echo $MAINPID > /var/run/redis/redis.pid"

then type

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload

> sudo systemctl enable redis-server

> sudo systemctl restart redis.service